# Dockerized react app doesnt hot reload on code change

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I want to start developing my React apps with docker, to get familiar with this tool but I am facing some crazy issues. I have seen a lot of tutorials on how to dockerize react app. I have followed all steps presented in that tutorials at some point the guy from the tutorial was doing the hot reload with docker on react app. And for me that doesn't work, I have seen the page for which I have created the container. So for me, the container wasn't updating and the tutorial guy does.

Because I have followed a lot of tutorials and articles about this topic and nothing has helped me I tried to get some pre-made template to figure it out. So I have cloned a repo with one of these templates. To my surprise, I am still facing the issue that I cant make a live reload.

This is the repo I cloned: https://github.com/rsandagon/docker-react-app-template

Now my file looks like this

Dockerfile

```
#base image
FROM node:9.6.1

#set working directory
RUN  mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR usr/src/app

#add `/usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

#install and cache app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-script@1.1.1 -g --silent

#start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.5'

services:

  docker-react-app-template:
    container_name: docker-react-app-template
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - '.:/usr/src/app'
      - '/usr/src/app/node_modules'
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
```

I have used these two commands:

```
docker-compose up -d --build
docker-compose start
```

First to create the image, second to run the container.
After these, I have still a page that doesn't hot reload when the App.js file changes.

Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong? I am lost. TY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using WSL2 as a backend for Docker Desktop, the project must be created on or copied directly to the Linux file system. If the project is on the Windows file system, the volumes will not work correctly. All docker commands should be run within WSL2 and not on Windows.

1. To open your WSL2 type wsl in the Search Bar.
2. When the WSL terminal launches, change into the WSL user directory by running the **cd ~ command**. Verify that you are in the correct location by running pwd. This should now printout **/home/USERNAME**. If it still shows **/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32**, you are in the wrong location.
3. Run **explorer.exe .** to open up the file explorer.
4. Move your project directory into the WSL file browser window.
5. Delete any **node_modules** or **package-lock.json** files that may exist in the project directory. If these were generated on the Windows file system and were copied over, they will conflict.
6. Using the WSL2 terminal build your Docker image as you typically would.

Comment: Thank you very much. This helped me a lot. But because I dont understand this stuff much I am still facing some issues from having a happy development as I had without docker.  How can I make a github repo from this file, when it is inside an Ubuntu folder? I think thats impossible. Do I need every time when I create a react app to put in inside Ubuntu folder? It is really hard and slow.

Comment: How can I make a github repo from this file, when it is inside an Ubuntu folder?
It's posible to make a github repo inside WSL2. There is a guide on how to do it:

[Get started using Git on Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-git). 

Do I need every time when I create a react app to put in inside Ubuntu folder?
Yes, volumes don't work correctly in the Windows file system.

Comment: Here is an in-depth answer to your second question: Linux containers only receive file change events (“inotify events”) if the original files are stored in the Linux filesystem. For example, some web development workflows rely on inotify events for automatic reloading when files have changed. [Best practices](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/wsl/#best-practices)

Comment: Nice, I will read through these materials. Thank you very much <3